# Saving Javascript FormData() Object on client side

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage, client-side

I have a html page which contains a form element with some text and file input elements.
This from is submitted with an ajax call to the server using a method suggested here: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously/8758614#8758614)

As you may see in the referenced page from the above link, the **FormData()** object is used as a container for inputed data and I have done the job successfully.

But now we want to create a new page that have these html elements, save the text and file inputs on client side (Cookie or Local Strorage or . . .) and do the ajax submit later on another page.

I wasn`t able to save **new FormData()** in either cookie or local storage; what got saved is a small string:"[object FormData]" instead of entered file and strings.

I also tried using JSON.stringify() with no success; it just returned an empty JSON("{}").

(the code is using jQuery selector)

```js
var postData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
// var sPostedData = JSON.stringify(postData); // returns: "{}"
var myStorage = window.localStorage; // returns: "[object FormData]"
myStorage.setItem("contentOrder", postData);
```

Please help, how should I save this object on my client-side?

Comment: localStorage only stores strings. Also you can't populate a `file` input with script. You need to re-think this process flow...especially if working with larger files since localStorage also has size limits

Comment: We have a shop web site and we what to add ability for customers to buy before login. I want to keep the user inputs until he logged in and then do the submit.

Comment: Could do the upload and store in session or temp file then do something else with it once logged in

Answer (score 1):

To get the file from form data use `formData.get('file')` where `file` is the name of an input. The returned object will be of type Blob ([see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) how to get its content).

The complete example can be found in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skm5m467/1/